# When taking integration of a constant, can things fundamentally be understood in the following way?

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int 1 \,dx $$
$$=1\int  \,dx $$
$$=1  \left[  x   \right] $$
$$=x$$

I mean, do we reason the integral of the constant as the constant coming out as it does in other questions, or is there some other logic at work here that I'm missing?

edit: I don't know if I can reply to comments, so here it is. I have added brackets just to show 1 and x being multiplied. It's given in my textbook while antiderivative is found.

Comment: What do you mean by the bracket notation $[x]$?

Comment: Also, are you interested in the *indefinite* integral (as you've written it without limits)? This is just a notational convenience for finding the family of antiderivatives of the given function.

Comment: @SammyBlack I made some edits. Yes, I am interested in the indefinite integral. I am in high school and currently this is being taught to us. So, I just got a random question if this is actually what happens under the hood.

Comment: The 1-form $1\,dx$ is equal to $dx$.  Or, in simpler language - $\int dx$ is just a shorthand for $\int 1 \, dx$ (under common calculus book definitions).

Comment: It's fine to write $\int dx = \int 1 dx$.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you've written is valid, but keep in mind that the indefinite integral notation
$$
\int f(x) \, dx
$$
describes the family of antiderivatives $F(x) + C$, where $F'(x) = f(x)$ and $C$ is any real number. So, it's typical to write
$$
\int 1 \, dx = x + C,  
$$
which is a family of parallel lines of slope $1$. It's only the particular antiderivative where $C = 0$ that yields the antiderivative $x$.

More generally, for any real number $m$, you can factor out the constant to obtain
$$
\int m \, dx = m \int 1 \, dx = mx + C, 
$$
a family of parallel lines of slope $m$.